# Jasper: horizontal main report causes the error "Subreport overflow on a band that does not support overflow"

Tags: jasper-reports

I've created a report, that you can find here:
[Jasper, 'print when' create white space,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057135/jasper-print-when-create-white-space/57057795#57057795)

**StackOverflowExample.jrxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.8.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.8.0-2ed8dfabb690ff337a5797129f2cd92902b0c87b  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StackOverflowExample" columnCount="2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="277" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="749cd048-9a0d-4a00-89bf-1a75a4565943">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT  "ORDERS"."SHIPCOUNTRY", 
    Max("ORDERS"."SHIPCOUNTRY") 
FROM  "ORDERS"

GROUP BY "ORDERS"."SHIPCOUNTRY" 
ORDER BY "ORDERS"."SHIPCOUNTRY" ASC]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="SHIPCOUNTRY" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SHIPCOUNTRY"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="ORDERS"/>
    </field>
    <field name="C2" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="C2"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="170">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="50" width="297" height="120" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="4b89b974-f838-4bb7-85b6-1b0f1079c1e6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="country">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPCOUNTRY}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["StackOverflowExampleSubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="43" y="0" width="185" height="50" uuid="0c170024-70ea-492f-95fe-99ff3a27cb6d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="19"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPCOUNTRY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**StackOverflowExampleSubReport.jrxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.8.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.8.0-2ed8dfabb690ff337a5797129f2cd92902b0c87b  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StackOverflowExample" columnCount="2" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="277" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="749cd048-9a0d-4a00-89bf-1a75a4565943">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <parameter name="country" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["France"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT "ORDERS"."ORDERDATE",
    "ORDERS"."FREIGHT"
FROM "ORDERS"
WHERE  "ORDERS"."SHIPCOUNTRY" = $P{country}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ORDERDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ORDERDATE"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="ORDERS"/>
    </field>
    <field name="FREIGHT" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="FREIGHT"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.tree.path" value="ORDERS"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="130">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()==1)]]></printWhenExpression>
            <lineChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="3" width="235" height="125" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3b5f7d89-490b-468f-9112-f606f4eda437"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$P{country}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORDERDATE}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{FREIGHT}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <linePlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </linePlot>
            </lineChart>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

This report works, what I have is this
https://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/user_uploads/ho.hince/capture_report_test.png

### The problem :

The order is vertical. What we can see is `Argentina, Brazil, Austria, Canada, etc..` But I want to have `Argentina, Austria, Belgium, Brazil, etc..`

If I change the print order to horizontal, I get the error :

> Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow.

The answer [Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660278/subreport-overflowed-on-a-band-that-does-not-support-overflow) tells that I have to use vertical, but I want it horizontal.
How can I solve it? Any ideas or tricks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detail band in horizontal reports is not allowed to stretch vertically, so you need to make it tall enough to fit the subreport.

In your report, the subreport element in the master report has height=120.  But the subreport has detail band with height=130, plus 20 pixels top margin and 20 bottom margin.  So the subreport actually takes 170 pixels in height.

If you set the height of the subreport element in the master report to 170 and the height of the master detail band to 220, it will work with horizontal print order.

Comment: You are actually a genius, I wish I could upvote twice. Thank you, it helped a lot.